# How can I display newline in playframework template?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to playframework. I was trying to use a form -where the textarea field receives multi-line string.

[image]

After processing the taxtarea form field, data
is stored in postgresql database.

[image]

But when I try to display the string pulling from database the `newLine` is not displayed in template.

[image]

Here is the template code -- `contactUs.message` is carrying the string data

```
 <div class="row">
        <p>
           @contactUs.message
        </p>

    </div>
```

How can I display newline in play template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops! It was my mistake, I should have used `pre` tag.

```
<div class="row">
        <pre>@contactUs.message</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you read from db or before you write to db replace new line (\r) with HTML br tag.

Comment: Actually `p` tag does not care \r. That was the mistake. I could use your idea. But in my case `pre` tag is perfect. I forgot about this.